# Display stream of byte array frames to textureview

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, gstreamer, textureview

I am trying to display a stream of frames received over network and display them to TextureView. My pipeline is as follows:

1. Receive video using GStreamer. I am using NDK. Gstreamer code is in C. I am using JNI callback to send individual frames received in appsink from C to Java. I do not want to use ANativeWindow from within the NDK to display to surface, as is done in the GStreamer Tutorial-3 example app.
2. In Java, these frames are added to a ArrayBlockingQueue. A separate thread pulls from this queue.

Following is the callback from pullFromQueue thread stays alive as long as app is running. The byte[] frame is a NV21 format frame of known width and height.

```
@DebugLog
private void pullFromQueueMethod() {
    try {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        byte frame[] = framesQueue.take();
    }
```

From here, I would like to use OpenGL to alter brightness, contrast and apply shaders to individual frames. Performance is of utmost concern to me and hence I **cannot** convert byte[] to Bitmap and then display to a SurfaceView. I have tried this and it takes nearly 50ms for a 768x576 frame on Nexus 5.

Surprisingly, I cannot find an example anywhere to do the same. All examples use either the Camera or MediaPlayer inbuilt functions to direct their preview to surface/texture. For example : `camera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);`. This links the output to a SurfaceTexture and hence you never have to handle displaying individual frames (never have to deal with byte arrays).

What I have attempted so far :

Seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443481/how-to-draw-buffer-to-a-textureview-on-android) answer on StackOverflow. It suggests to use Grafika's `createImageTexture()`. Once I receive a Texture handle, how do I pass this to SurfaceTexture and continuously update it? Here is partial code of what I've implemented so far :

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

int textureId = -1;
SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture;
TextureView textureView;

...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    textureView = new TextureView(this);
    textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
}

private void pullFromQueueMethod() {
try {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    byte frame[] = framesQueue.take();

    if (textureId == -1){
        textureId = GlUtil.createImageTexture(frame);
        surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(textureId);
        textureView.setSurfaceTexture(surfaceTexture);
    } else {
        GlUtil.updateImageTexture(textureId); // self defined method that doesn't create a new texture, but calls GLES20.glTexImage2D() to update that texture
    }

    surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();

    /* What do I do from here? Is this the right approach? */

}
}
```

To sum up. All I really need is an efficient manner to display a stream of frames (byte arrays). How do I achieve this?

Comment: it's me again, can you post your answer? I will vote it up!

Comment: I've put up the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53149338/6844926)

Comment: So is this question a duplicate of the one which posted the answer on?